# How to avoid ASP.NET website being hacked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

AFAIK attackers can overwrite files which have CHMOD values 777 on linux servers. Today my web site which created by myself using ASP.NET has been hacked. My Site.master page has been appended with lots of backlinks and there was a folder named as Sayers which has many html files (probably include search keys).

I could easily delete the folder and restore the original Site.master file.

I do not have SQL injection problem. Even if so I would have seen some additions or changes in the records. There is nothing. There are only changed files and added folder.

I have updated my FTP password. I am 100% sure that I do not use a third party extension. All the code is handmade (: So I want to know how to prevent this to be done again. Also what could be the vulnerability about the website. I also want to know if it is a server side problem or my problem.

I am using a hosting company's service. I use FTP (21), not secure.

Comment: recommend posting here http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons: Windows updates you haven't installed. Security bug in any other software accepting connections. Third party controls with their own config page. Do you have any pointers *where* it is going wrong?

Comment: Are you using secure FTP? Are you running your own server or are you on a shared host?